# Can codeigniter support Inline functions.?

Tags: php, codeigniter, inline-functions

Can we write multiple functions inside another function in Codeigniter.? here is my controlller

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {

  public function myproduct() {
      $this->load->view('myproduct'); // call myproduct.php

           public function features() {
              $this->load->view('features');  // call "myproduct/features"
            }

           public function screenshots() {
              $this->load->view('screenshots');  // call "myproduct/screenshots"
            }
    }
}
```

as per my controller there are 2 inline functions inside myproduct(). my aim isto display the url as

```
localhost/mysite/products/myproduct
localhost/mysite/products/myproduct/features
localhost/mysite/products/myproduct/screenshots
```

i already tried it but it gives me a error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in D:\...........\application\controllers\mysite\products.php on line 5
```

and the line 5 was

```
public function features() { .........
```

Comment: why you  need function inside a function?

Comment: in `myproduct` method take parameters and solve with conditions. you can not add any method inside,

Comment: No, you won't be able to load a method inside a method, and really you don't want to. What exactly are you wanting to get from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just treat this as a uri paramater in the url:

```
public function myproduct($param = null) 
{
    if($param == null) {
        $this->load->view('myproduct'); 
    } elseif($param == 'features') {
        $this->load->view('features');
    } elseif ($param == 'screenshots') {
        $this->load->view('screenshots');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something in codeigniter... This is generally not possible in PHP. You can work with closures, but they dont render the desired effect in your case.

Try reading [CodeIgniter URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to understand the principles of routing within codeigniter. Than create the separate functions in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve or how you plan to call/use these functions and in which scope but in order to declare a function inside a function you do this:

```
public function myproduct(){

    $t = 'myproduct';

    $features = function($t = '', &$this = ''){
        // some code goes here

        $this->load->view('features'); // will NOT work

        $this->load->view($t.'/features'); // this should work
    };

    $features($t, $this); // load the features view

}
```

This should be your goal though:

```
public function myproduct($uri_piece = ''){

    $this->load->view('myproduct/'.$uri_piece);

}
```

Comment: I think neither `$this` nor `$t` is in the scope of an anonymous function.